# save html content into a txt file using python3

Tags: python

I'm tired of searching and trying codes that give repetitive errors, I really hope someone will help me figure this out.
my probleme is so simple
I'm trying to save an html code in a txt file using python, here's the code I'm using:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
url1 = 'http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/menu-de-la-semaine.aspx'
page = uReq(url1).read().decode()
f = open("test.html", "w")
f.write(page)
f.close()
```

but it's giving me the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2665' in position 416224: character maps to

Comment: Why are you using `.decode()` ? Why not just take the output of the reader and stream it into the file?

Comment: I tried not using it but it gives me another error `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`

Comment: What is `uReq`??

Comment: oh! sorry i forgot the import statement, i will add it right away, here's what the uReq is `from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq`

Comment: you are reading a webpage without even considering the `charset` - no handling for it??

Comment: I'm just a beginner on python and have no experience with that so may you clarify how should I use that? cause seriously I've looked everywhere and it feels like no one has the answer to that!

Comment: you should just have save with 'wb' write as binary and dont use decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated solution:

**Python 2.x:**

```
import urllib

url1 = 'http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/menu-de-la-semaine.aspx'
page = urllib.urlopen(url1).read()
f = open("./test1.html", "w")
f.write(page)
f.close()
```

**Python 3.x:**

```
import urllib.request
import shutil

url1 = 'http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/menu-de-la-semaine.aspx'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url1)
print(page)
f = open("./test2.html", "wb")
shutil.copyfileobj(page, f)
f.close()
```

You need to use `urllib` to help you achieve this task.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that my version 3.6

Answer (score 0):

You should try with requests and bs4 (BeautifulSoup)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503845/save-html-content-into-a-txt-file-using-python")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print(soup)
with open ('/tmp/test.html', 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: that was a bit hopeful but it's still showing the same error on my ide `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2665' in position 360940: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: weird, I just tried with your link and worked well for me

Answer (score 0):

You mention that by not using the .decode() method gives you A Type Error. Have you try to take the HTML content and pass it to the write() method as a string. You may find the way to enclose the HTML content with triple quotes, so you pass it as a multiline string.

Comment: that didn't work either, I mentioned it in a previous comment up there